# How to use YoLo4 custom model (yolov4-tflite)with input type float32 and detect object in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow-lite, yolo, yolov4

I like to integrate the custom yoLo4 model and detect the particular objects that are accessible through a model. I am unable to pass the float32 input type, get the interpreter, and detect the object.